# Unable to add LinearLayout as a first child in Umano's AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

In [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel#usage), Usage says..

> To use the layout, simply include com.sothree.slidinguppaneldemo.SlidingUpPanelLayout as the Root element in your activity Layout. Make sure that it has two children. The first child is your main layout. The second child is your layout for the sliding up panel. Both children should have width and height set to match_parent. The following code is the sample code included in library.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DemoActivity" >

<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Main Content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eee"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/brought_by"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:text="Brought to you by http://umanoapp.com"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/graphic" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

The result of above xml layout is

[image]

I replaced the first child layout `TextView`(Main Content) with `LinearLayout`(any layouts) and it gives `NullPointerException` in Graphical Layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Close your layout by adding:

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

after

```
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Comment: its already included in the code, Its missing here in this snippet.

Comment: I'm looking at their demo project, try to wrap your 2 TextViews ('The Awesome Sliding Up Panel' and 'Brought by' in another LinearLayout, as seen here: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/demo/res/layout/activity_demo.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please check the usage of the **[Umano library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel#usage)** for your app. Here it is clear written that there should be **exact two layout as child** in the slidingUpPanel view. You can take it as any layout.

I have already try same thing with the **RelativeLayout** and **LinearLayout** and it works like charm.

Please let me know if your issue not resolved by this.

Enjoy Coding... :)